# SerialPort.DataReceived doesn't work in Windows Service / Session Zero

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

The DataReceived event never gets called in a C# .NET service running in session zero BUT does in a console app or service running in the current user session.
Am I missing some permission?

```
/// <summary>
        /// Opens the first avaliable COM port that matches the vid/pid
        /// </summary>
        public static bool OpenComDevice(string vid, string pid, out SerialPort serialPort)
        {
            serialPort = null;

            // find server com port
            var regPortNames = ComPortNames(vid, pid);
            foreach (string name in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                if (regPortNames.Contains(name))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        serialPort = new SerialPort(name);
                        serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
                        serialPort.Open();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        if (serialPort != null)
                        {
                            serialPort.Dispose();
                            serialPort = null;
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            return serialPort != null;
        }

private void Connect()
        {
            if (!Utils.OpenComDevice("239A", "801E", out serial)) return;
            DebugLog.Log("Connected: " + serial.PortName);

            serial.DataReceived += Serial_DataReceived;
            serial.PinChanged += Serial_PinChanged;
            serial.ErrorReceived += Serial_ErrorReceived;

            isConnected = true;
            ConnectedEvent?.Invoke(serial.PortName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET for a Windows Service you need to call Dispatcher.Run()